# Speaker and mic connection

Tags: electronics, microphones, live-sound

Can I connect 1 wired mic to 2 PA system so the both of them can work?

I have 2 public address systems and one wired mic. How can I use the one wired mic to connect to the both speakers all at once?

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the exact makes and models of the microphone and the PAs? Or as much detail as you have available?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes.

I will assume that your facility has one PA system wired to one bank of speakers, and a second/ancillary PA system wired to a different set of speakers.

Plug your mic cable into Line 1 of the first PA head.
Sound-check the microphone with a compatriot, and set the Volume and EQ levels to the most pleasing sound.

Next, plug an instrument cable or speaker cable into either the Monitor Out or Main Out of the first PA head and into Line 1 of the second PA head.

Leaving the master volume of the second PA head fairly low, conduct a second sound-check. Bring the master volume of that PA up slow, checking for feedback.
Adjust the Volume and EQ levels for that PA, and roll the Volume down a bit once you encounter feedback.

Please note that the location and position of the microphone in question should be place precisely where the intended performer will be standing later on.
The more speakers there are in a venue, the more important the location/position of the microphone during the sound check.

If your performer or speech-giver intends to roam all over the stage (or pace around during the performance), make sure you sound-check the microphone for all conceivable locations. I have found that I must set tape marks on the floor of the venue, to show the performer or speech-giver their left and right limits for avoiding feedback.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I connect my two PA systems two ways.  One is to use main outs from a mixer console, one connect to line in, on each PA. Mics and instruments are connected to the mixer.  The other is to connect the PAs by line out of one to the line input of the other.  The mixer is used to connect several mics and instruments but with one mic it is not needed.  Portable PAs and powered speakers many times have XLR inputs for mics.  Plug the mic to one PA then connect the line out from it to the other PA's line input. Adjust EQ and volumes on each as needed.